# How to Embed Views Exposed Filter for only one field

Tags: views

i have a view and many fields are exposed in it. I need to embed (render) a specific exposed filter in my template.

i have came across [this](http://www.butlerraines.com/post/drupal-7-views-3-how-programmatically-embed-views-exposed-filter) article. But it shows all exposed filters of a view.

any idea how this can be done?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a views tpl file with name *views-exposed-form--view-name.tpl.php* in your theme in this file `<?php print_r($widgets); exit; ?>` this will give you your widgets then print your widget like this: `print $widgets['your widget name']->widget ;` in end  `print $button;`

Comment: there is no way to print it directly in page tpl file?

Comment: no there is no way to do it directly